# What is the term for two vectors pointed 180 degrees apart?

Tags: geometry, terminology

Two vectors that are 90 degrees apart are orthogonal. What is the term when the two are separate by a half turn, ie. pointing opposite directions?

Comment: Anti-parallel is the usual term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've mostly seen them written as anti-parallel vectors.